# Python programs slow to start in VS Code terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I run any program in the VS Code terminal, the program takes about 20-30 seconds before it starts running. After it starts, it runs at relatively normal speeds.

This is new behavior: code I was running last school year had much faster startup times. I am using no new extensions I am aware of that would be slowing this down- I have tried disabling extensions I don't need, but to no avail. None of the listed startup times appear to be the problem (Python extension's time is 282 ms, and that's the longest listed startup time).

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code, and also tried installing Python 3.10.0 (I am using 3.9.0 by default).

Here is a sample of code that shouldn't take much time to start up, but does:

```
var = 1
while True:
    print(var)
    var += 1
```

This slow-start behavior is the same across all Python programs I've been running, infinite loop or no.

```
VS Code info:
Version: 1.61.2 (user setup)
Commit: 6cba118ac49a1b88332f312a8f67186f7f3c1643
Date: 2021-10-19T14:57:20.575Z
Electron: 13.5.1
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
```

FYI, I am a programming teacher, with no educational background in programming. I promise I'll do my best to answer your questions, but I may need some handholding to get there. Thank you for any help.

Edit: I've been in the habit of killing the terminal when I make changes to a program, then saving my program, then running it. I kill the terminal a lot. It turns out that if I only save and rerun my program (without killing the terminal), the first run starts slow, but then subsequent runs start just fine. This leads me to believe that the problem isn't with the program itself, but with my terminal starting slowly.

Comment: I would also try with another IDE for Python, like Pycharm which is a popular and free one (not sure if you've checked that out already, in which case feel free to disregard this)

Comment: You indicated that you tried reinstalling VS Code and Python; however when I search "VS Code terminal slow python Windows 10", there are many many results and suggestions for fixes. You haven't indicated what research you've done or if you've done any of those fixes; please either go and try those if you haven't already, or list in detail what solutions you've attempted so far, so it doesn't look like you posted this without first doing research. It'll also help us not waste our time giving solutions you've already tried.

Comment: @mvery understood. My questions still stand though

Comment: I should have mentioned- these problems don't replicate in Python or IDLE; programs happen at normal speeds. Same with Sublime Text- program starts instantly. This seems isolated to VS Code for some reason. All the other StackOverflow posts I've found don't seem to mention problems on startup. I've tried most of the suggestions on [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/optimize-vscode-performance-best-extensions/] and [https://vscode.one/make-vscode-faster/] for general guidance, but neither seemed to help.

Comment: Sorry for spamming these comments, but I just stumbled across something that seems relevant. I've been in the habit of killing the terminal when I make changes to a program, then saving my program, then running it. I kill the terminal a lot. It turns out that if I only save and rerun my program (without killing the terminal), the first run starts slow, but then subsequent runs start just fine. This leads me to believe that the problem isn't with the program itself, but with my terminal starting slowly.

Comment: How do you run your python programs? Do you manually type the command in the terminal or do you use the "Run" button in VS Code? The latter creates a new Terminal which if you are using Windows might be using Powershell which takes a while to start

Comment: What about creating a new terminal with the shortcut of Ctrl+Shift+`.

Comment: @AzuxirenLeadGuy & Steven-MSFT- I use the run button. If I don't kill the terminal and keep hitting the run button, the program starts running again almost immediately. Opening the terminal in VS Code (with ctrl + shft + `) seems to take a rather long time, but once it's open, the program starts almost immediately

Comment: @mvery Okay. I really think the issue is that you're using Powershell terminal instead of CMD (i.e the issue has nothing to do with python). Can you include the content of the terminal *before* your python file is executed? Make a simple python program adding two integers and printing output, and paste the *entire* content, including before the start of the program.

Comment: @AzuxirenLeadGuy That's the suspicion I'm having as well. Here's the whole content of the terminal after running print(1+ 2): `Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\mvery> & C:/Users/mvery/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/mvery/OneDrive - Diocese of Greensburg Schools/Desktop/demo.py"
3
PS C:\Users\mvery> `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from your comments, I'm pretty sure the problem is not python or VS Code in your system, but PowerShell taking a much longer time to start.

I would advise you to switch to CMD, which takes much less time to start. Go to `setting.json` and add the line

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
```

Alternatively, you can click the `+` button in the integrated terminal, select `Default Profile` and select `Command Prompt` when the prompt appears on the top of the screen, as shown in the [documentation of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles)

If you want to fix PowerShell being slow itself, there are a lot of answers available online. You seem to be using an older version of PowerShell. You can update it to PowerShell Core 6, but  I don't think it would be necessary. Changing the default profile to CMD should be enough to solve your issue.

Comment: This did it! Thank you! I've started looking into speeding up PowerShell

Comment: Where is this? "Go to setting.json and add the line"

Comment: @JQTs Open the command palette (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`) and type `setting.json`. Select the link "Preferences: Open User Setting (JSON)". This opens a file containing commands of all your changed settings in JSON. At the end of commands (Just before the final closing brace `}` in the file), add a comma to the last line(if not present already) and then add the given line "terminal....." at the end